# script to remove redundant lines from two different files

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, grep

I will explain my problem with an example

I have the following files in `Solaris`

*file1*:

```
1 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U386.A0 I have some text here 
1 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U386.A1 I have some text here 
2 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U246.A0 I have some text here 
2 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U246.A1 I have some text here 
3 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A0 I have some text here 
3 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A1 I have some text here 
3 INST C 1 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U64.A1  I have some text here 
4 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A0 I have some text here 
4 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A1 I have some text here
5 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A0 I have some text here 
5 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A1 I have some text here 
6 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U375.A0 I have some text here 
6 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U375.A1 I have some text here 
7 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U98.A   I have some text here 
8 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U392.A0 I have some text here 
8 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U392.A1 I have some text here 
9 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U372.A0 I have some text here 
10 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U372.A1 I have some text here 
11 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U184.A  I have some text here 
12 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U97.B   I have some text here
```

*file2*:

```
INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A0
INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A1
INST C 1 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U64.A1 
INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A0
INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A1
INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A0
INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A1
```

Now i have `file2` as reference and print all the lines that match in `file1`

Expected output is:

```
3 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A0 I have some text here 
3 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A1 I have some text here 
3 INST C 1 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U64.A1  I have some text here 
4 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A0 I have some text here 
4 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A1 I have some text here 
5 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A0 I have some text here 
5 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A1 I have some text here
```

I have tried `grep`:

```
grep -F -x -f file1 -v file2 > file3
```

and `fgrep`:

```
fgrep -x -f file1 -v file2 > file3
```

based on several posts from *stackoverflow*. But didnt find what i need. Since i am a starter, I am really confused to find a way out of this. Your help is most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for you:

```
grep -Ff file2 file1 >file3
```

test with your files:

```
kent$  grep -Ff f2 f1
3 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A0 I have some text here
3 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U385.A1 I have some text here
3 INST C 1 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U64.A1 I have some text here
4 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A0 I have some text here
4 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U384.A1 I have some text here
5 INST N 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A0 I have some text here
5 INST C 0 top.gbp.stg1.stg2.stg3.stg4.stg5.stg6.stg6.U390.A1 I have some text here
```

Comment: Can you also help me with How to get  the lines that are different in two files as output?

Comment: @CHEPTHA try `grep -vFf file2 file1 >file3` if this doesn't do what you want, post a new question please.